# I have added product to the trolley by using selenium web driver JAVA and I removed it from the cart. How can I assert the product is removed or not?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, assertion, cucumber-java

This is my remove the product from the trolley or cart.

```
public class TrolleyPage(){
     public void removeFromTrolley() {
        List<WebElement> removeProductBtnList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[data-test='basket-removeproduct']"));
        int size = removeProductBtnList.size();
        System.out.println("Number of size of Added product in trolley " + size);
        WebElement removedWebElement = removeProductBtnList.get(0);
        removedWebElement.click();
    }
}
```

It is working.
I have stored the "product name" in the List from the trolley To verify the the product available in the trolley or not after removing, but it is getting assertion error.

```
public class TrolleyPage(){
    public List<String> getAllProductsInTrolley() {
        List<String> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<WebElement> productWebElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[data-e2e='product-name']"));
        for (WebElement product : productWebElements) {
            String productName = product.getText();
            if (!productName.isEmpty()) {
                actualList.add(productName);
                System.out.println("Product :" + productName);
            }
        }
        return actualList;
    }
}
```

This is my actual List and I want to compare to expected how can I assert please help me

```
public class RemoveTheProductDefs {

    private TrolleyPage trolleyPage = new TrolleyPage();
    private String expected;


  @When("^I remove a product$")
    public void i_remove_a_product()  {
        trolleyPage.removeFromTrolley();

    }
--------- This is failing-------
    @Then("^I should see the the trolley is empty$")
    public void i_should_see_the_the_trolley_is_empty()  {
        List<String> actualList = trolleyPage.getAllProductsInTrolley();
  
        assertThat(actualList,contains(expected));    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and naive fix might be comparing the size of List.

`sizeAfter = sizeBefore - 1`

```
private int sizeBefore;

@Given("^I added products to trolley$")
public void i_added_products_to_trolley()  {
    ...
    sizeBefore = trolleyPage.getAllProductsInTrolley().size();
}

...

@Then("^I should see the number of product in trolley decrease one$")
public void i_should_see_the_number_of_product_in_trolley_decrease_one()  {
    int sizeAfter = trolleyPage.getAllProductsInTrolley().size();
    assertThat(sizeAfter , equalTo(sizeBefore - 1));    
}
```